# Installer Error while Installing SQL Server Reporting Services

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a Windows 2008 R2 Server 64bit, I have already installed SQL Server 2008 R2 SP2 64bit Enterprise Edition, Which is working fine, without any issues.

Now when I am trying to install Reporting Services I get the following error.

[image]

I have googled and got nowhere, any ideas why this is happening, obviously the error messages suggests there is something wrong with the installer but Vendor claims its fine and it should work. Am I missing something? any suggestions any pointers in the right direction is much appreciated. Thank you.

Error Log can see found here [`Error Log`](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=e106ef08b6c4c676&id=E106EF08B6C4C676%21602)

Comment: Duplicated of: [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/75012/installer-error-while-installing-sql-server-reporting-services)

Comment: Yes I know, since there is audience for this question on both platforms.

Comment: Did you look in the log file to see if there are any clues there?

Comment: His log file: [log](https://onedrive.live.com/?cid=e106ef08b6c4c676&id=E106EF08B6C4C676%21602)

Comment: Check if `OWC11.MSI` does exist at the location mentioned? Try to run the file OWC11.MSI manually see if it works? Or download a fresh copy of the file from internet and replace it with your current one.

Comment: OWC11.MSI is office 2003 web components file. http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/help/locate-missing-msi-files-HA001118572.aspx Definition of MSI file: 
 `"An .msi file is a database of all the files, settings, and configuration information for the associated application. When you install Office on your computer, the .msi file is saved in a hidden folder. Without this file, Windows Installer cannot update your configuration, install optional features, or apply software updates."`